# What does "Acaso Dios es el acaso" mean?

Tags: significado

> Acaso Dios es el acaso

It came from this article:

http://luvina.com.mx/foros/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=398&Itemid=45

Google translate says:

> It Is God harassment

But I'm pretty sure that's not it. I think it's more something along of lines of: "Is it that God is chance"?

I think what I want to understand is what "el acaso" is. Is it "the chance"?

Comment: I think Google is confusing acaso with acoso

Comment: Para empezar me cuesta encontrarle un significado a la frase en español, busque en RAE y "acaso" no tiene mas significados que desconozca, podria llegar a ser un error de tipeo y en realidad quiera decir _"Acaso Dios es el **o**caso"_. En tal caso seria una comparación con la puesta de sol.

Comment: @Marco, yo creo que la palabra esta bien, solo que pareciera no tener mucho sentido o que se medio contradice, en relación a lo que uno consideraría que es Dios. Pero otra forma de decirlo seria: "Será que Dios es el azar"

Comment: @mdewey, si definitivamente lo esta confundiendo con "acoso". :/

Comment: Leyendo el párrafo de donde procede, a mi me cuesta encontrarle un significado a cualquier parte del mismo, no sólo a esa frase en concreto.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the repetition in Spanish into English I think 'Perchance God is chance' is your best bet. Note however that perchance is an archaic word only familiar in the quote 'to sleep, perchance to dream'.

Answer (score 1):

I having spanish as mother languange I think this sentence has a very ironic meaning but anyway, is not the Bible full with those?. If you are considering the literal translation for **Acaso Dios es el acaso** then **Is God perhaps "the maybe"?** is the best answer.

For a more common use **Is God by any chance "the maybe"?** will fit perfectly.

As @mdewey mentioned before *Google Translator* is considering the second **acaso (perhaps)** with **acoso (harassment)**

Answer (score 0):

El un expresion popular en Sur América. Cuando una persona tiene un ego algo alto o se cree que es invencible se usa esta expresión.

Ejemplo:

> -Pero él es muy bueno en lo que hace no puedo superarlo , ¿Acaso él es dios?